# Access property of isolated scope from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I access isolated scope's property in directive tag?
Simplified example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('myController', function() {
        var result_el = document.getElementById("result");
        this.log = function(text) {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerHTML = text;
            result_el.appendChild(p);
        }
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                'click_fn': '&myClick'
            },
            template: '<span ng-click="click_fn()">Click me!</span>',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.my_prop = 'text property';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController as mCtrl">
    <my-directive my-click="mCtrl.log(my_prop)"></my-directive>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

In this example I need to get `my_prop` property from directive's scope. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive definition object for isolate scope (DDO)should be as below

```
 scope: {
         click_fn: '&myClick' // click_fn should not be string 
       },
```

In directive template , need to pass parameter in object literal (aliasing)as below

**Directive template**

```
template: '<span ng-click="click_fn({my_prop:my_prop})">Click me!</span>'
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YP60FQmX4RtN1fnfuQn8?p=preview)